# Changing the position of datepicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datepicker, position

I am using simple datepicker but its position is not where I want it to be. Here is a screenshot of where it is opening[image: current position]

Here is where I want it to be(I have changed it by using inspect element)
[image]

Here is the code where I am using javascript for this datepicker.
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should put your HTML control rather than JavaScript..

Comment: can you elaborate it a bit more @AliShahrokhi

Comment: It means put your .aspx page?